# How Can Macbooks Be Connected to Portable Displays?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

How can a Macbook be connected to a portable display so people accustomed to large monitors can have a second display when working in a vacation home, hotel, or other home-away-from home?

Comment: It has been a while since we did these "share your best tipps and ideas" kind of posts, but for once I see some value in this. You may want to split your answer into several answers though (one per idea/solution), and turn them into community wiki posts.

Comment: Cost considerations run afoul of our “no shopping” questions guidance - we may have to discuss this on [meta] if it garners close votes for that reason.

Comment: I have removed cost from the question and given it a more secondary presence in the answers.  I don't think it was ever a "shopping" question because relative cost *effectiveness* of a technical solution is a legitimate question.  However, I've hopefully removed any ambiguity.  I agree that more clearly defining what constitutes "shopping" would be worthwhile but I'm not inclined to get into that right now on Meta.  Would rather be led by the moderators here.

Comment: Wonderful simplification of the problem to be solved. Hopefully that lets some good answers thrive

Answer (score 2):

**An iPad with Apple Sidecar**.  If you already own an iPad it's an obvious choice.  It's easy and wireless (except requires charging).   It's also extremely light and space-efficient.

Cons:

- If you don't already own an ipad it's a relatively expensive solution.
- It's small unless you go with the 13 inch Pro but if you can spend $1100 on a 13 inch travel monitor you probably can afford to have your advance team set up your workstation before your arrive :)
- It requires that both devices be signed in to iCloud.  Fine if you already do that, maybe unacceptable if you've chosen not to.

[image]

Comment: I would remove cost. Everyone has a price for their time and a price for their impact on the environment. Why label anything as outrageous? If you address functionality and quality - people can look up their prices quite easily I find in practice.

Comment: Cost effectiveness is an important consideration in any technical solution to a problem.  I confess that in this particular answer I went beyond "effectiveness" and added some judgmental comments.  I could have said "relatively" rather than "outrageously".  Maybe I'll tone this down a bit.

Comment: I don’t disagree on cost being important - the problem is we intend to be useful world wide and the cost of the same thing varies so greatly we have decided we’re not the place for that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**An Android tablet with an Airplay receiver app**.

A 10 inch Android tablet can be thin, light and robust.  It can be completely wireless, just needs charging. In addition to being your monitor you also have a tablet you can use and it's a great digital photo frame with the right app, and great for kids or you to play games.   Unlike Sidecar the Airplay receiver app works locally and doesn't require either device to "join" anything.

It's much more cost effective than a physically similar iPad with Sidecar if this is the sole purpose.

If you happen to own a large (14 inch say) Android tablet it might be an excellent choice but they are a lot more expensive than the ubiquitous 10 inch ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**A self-supporting wired portable display**.

A standalone display designed for portability is one way.

A 15" portable monitor with a built-in kick stand may be the most economical approach to large screen real estate, thinness and and light weight at low cost.   It's big enough to double as a display for movies or slide shows and can slip into your Macbook protective sleeve.

At time of writing there are 15.6" FHD IPS ones available at $145 and  12 inch ones for under $100 that weigh only 1.3 lbs.

Cons:

- It can only be used on a desk and with power.  If you're sitting on a bed or in a car, not that you really would need a second monitor, but the fully wireless options are not there.
- It's only a monitor.  When not being used as a travel monitor it has no other use.  But for the price you can afford to make it part of your travel kit.
- Cables.  It needs two cables, one for power and one for video from your Mac, and on a Macbook with two ports it consumes one of them .. or you need to add a little port replicator to your bag, which isn't such a big deal.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**A lid-mounted slideout monitor**.

Similar to a self-standing portable monitor but designed to attach to your laptop lid and slide out from behind it.  These look nice but are not effective at their job.  They have all the cons of all the other options, and no pros.  They are small.  They make the laptop top-heavy so the lid has to be vertical.  It's hard to point them the exact way you want.  And the hardware for storing them on your lid, and sliding them in and out, makes them heavy and expensive.  They require cables.  They cannot be used for anything else (they are not tablets, just monitors).  They are not as good at sharing,eg movies or slide shows as a larger, cheaper, more versatile standalone 15 inch model.

They ARE good if used in a setting where there is not enough desk space to stand a standalone monitor.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**[No!] A convertible or detachable Chromebook with Airplay**.

**Note:** at this time you can't have an airplay receiver on a Chromebook.  [It doesn't work.](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc#check_for_networking_requirements) I tried installing one from Google Play.  It runs, it broadcasts and is visible to the Macbook as an Airplay display but the Macbook cannot actually connect to it because of the limitation noted in that link.

Perhaps there are other third-party apps that would need to be installed on both the Macbook and Chromebook, with connection initiated from the Chromebook?

Also, if said Chromebook happens to be one your child got from school it is probably policy-locked out of Google Play so you can't install anything on it anyway.

[image]